# What does third derivative tell about inflection point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was trying to find the nature (maxima, minima, inflection points) of the function $$\frac{x^5}{20}-\frac{x^4}{12}+5=0$$

But I faced a conceptual problem. It is given in the solution to the problem that $f''(0)=0$ and $f'''(0) \neq 0$ so $0$ is not an inflection point. But why should we check the third derivative?

Isn't checking first and second derivative sufficient for verifying an inflection point ? 
Why must the higher order odd derivatives be zero for an inflection point?

Comment: What is your definition of inflection point? I think that this is important.

Comment: Where curve changes its concavity...

Comment: In this case, $\;f''(0)=f'''(0)=0\;$ , but $\;f^{(iv)}(0)=-2\neq0\implies x=0\;$ is *not* an extremum point of $\;f'(x)\;\implies x=0\;$ is *not* an inflextion point.

Answer (score 4):

An inflection point is where a curve changes from concave to convex or vice versa. There are two types of inflection points: *stationary* and *non-stationary*. Stationary means that at this point the slope (thus $f'$) is $0$. These points are also called **saddle-points**.

**Non-stationary inflection points** are different. They are where the slope is at maximum, i.e. you have to maximize $f'$ in order to find them. You know from caculus that you need to look at both the $f'$ and $f''$ derivatives to determine whether a $f$ has a maximum. But now, since we look for maxima of $f'$, we have to look at $f''$ **and**  $f'''$.

Comment: Wait a second.For $f'(x)=0 , f''(x)=0 $ and $f'''(x) \neq 0$ tells us that it is a stationary turning point or non stationary?

Comment: $f'' = 0$ must be too, else it's a maximum/minimum

Comment: Sorry sorry.Look at my question now.Please.

Comment: i meant, it's stationary, else it's a maximum/minimum

Comment: Where did you find these called saddle points? I've often seen that term used for functions of two variables; never for just one.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's pretty common http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SaddlePoint.html

Comment: Is there any published book or refereed paper where this usage appears?

Answer (score 3):

> It is given in the solution to the problem that $f''(0)=0$ and $f'''(0) \neq 0$ so $0$ is not an inflection point.

That makes no sense.

If $f''(a)=0$ and $f'''(a) \ne0$ (i.e. $f'''(a)$ is actually some well defined number and that number is not $0$), and then there **is** an inflection point at $a.$

But if $f''(a)=0$ and $f'''(a)=0,$ that information does not justify such a conclusion. In some cases where this happens there is an inflection point at $a$ and in some cases there is not.

To see this, assume $f''(a)=0$ and $f'''(a)>0.$ Then there is some open interval about $a$ in which $f''$ is positive to the right of $a$ and negative to the left. That means $f''$ changes sign at $a,$ so there is an inflection point.

And similarly if $f'''(a)<0.$

But $f(x)=x^4$ has $f''(0)=0$ and $f'''(0)=0$ and there is no inflection point anywhere, whereas $f(x) = x^5$ has $f''(0)=0$ and $f'''(0)=0$ and there is an inflection point at $0.$

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of inflection point. You have given this as

`"Where curve changes its concavity"`.

In this case checking $f'''(x)$ is not necessary since for example,

$$f(x) = x^3 \text{ gives } f'''(x) = 6 \neq 0 $$ however $x  = 0$ is an inflection point since there is a [change in concavity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) here.

Answer (score 0):

The given solution appears to be partially incorrect.

In fact
\begin{align}
f''(x) &= x^3 - x^2 = (x - 1)x^2 & f''(0) &= 0 & f''(1) &= 0 \\
f'''(x) &= 3x^2 - 2x & f'''(0) &= 0& f'''(1) &= 1, \\
\end{align}
and $f''$ has a double root (and local maximum) at $x=0$ and a single root at $x=1.$
At $x=0$, $f''$ is negative both on the left side and on the nearby right side of $x=0,$ but $f''$ is negative to the left of $x=1$ and positive to right, so $f$ has an inflection point at $x=1$ and not at $x=0.$

The value of the third derivative gives useful information at $x=1$ but not so much at $x=0.$ As noted in a comment, however, the fourth derivative at $x=0$ provides some useful information.